# Error on using Derivatives API on trial account

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

**Problem**

We created an app under an active trial account.
We added this app to the BIM 360.
We use this app properties to access model derivatives.
We get authorization error while accessing the model manifest.

```
{ "developerMessage":"You are not allowed to use this API because your Forge trial is expired.", "moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/", "errorCode": "ERR-004”}
```

We call next method

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/URN/manifest
```

Why we get message about "trial is expired" if it's not?

**Possible reason**

Something went wrong during the trial account creation.
If you go to forge.autodesk.com > Forge Account Details > Cloud Credit Balance > Active Trials, you will see progress indicator and no details.

**Workaround**

Create or use another one account and check Active Trials page. If you can see "days left" and "credits used" info, then everything must be ok.